# simple sql (i hope!)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Given a data set similar to this:

```
ccy | time | fxrate
GBP | 11   | 1.2
EUR | 21   | 1.4
CHF | 9    | 3.1
GBP | 15   | 1.1
EUR | 20   | 1.5
CHF | 1    | 3.0
CHF | 7    | 3.0
GBP | 20   | 1.9
```

I want to get the latest fxrates (by 'time') for each ccy:

```
ccy | time | fxrate
GBP | 20   | 1.9
EUR | 21   | 1.4
CHF | 9    | 3.1
```

Is it possible to get this data with a single sql query?  My skills are failing me.  I assume I need to GROUP BY ccy..?  where max(time) ..? LIMIT 1 ..?  Help!

[EDIT] using postgresql

Comment: the 'time' column

Comment: I didn't realize those integer values were timestamps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: @jarlh thanks - i was just trying to simplify the dataset as much as possible.  Maybe too much.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use `group by` for only max fxrate but in your case you need a correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.fxrate = (select max(t1.fxrate) from table t1 where t1.ccy = t.ccy);
```

In postgresql you can do :

```
select distinct on (ccy) *
from table t
order by t.fxrate desc;
```

Comment: It works (the 1st version) but I'm struggling to prevent it from doing a full table scan so it's slow.  Playing with the indexes now.

Comment: @pomo Try the second query as it's a much better way than the first, but change the order by to `order by ccy, time desc` - that should be both correct and fast.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work.  It's slow though.  It's doing a full table scan.  Guess I'm missing an index.

Answer (score 2):

row_number can be helpful

```
select * from (select *,row_number()over(partition by ccy order by time desc) rn
from table_name
) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's incredibly slow.  It's doing a full table scan even though I (think) I have the correct indexes in place.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use an inner join on sub query for max time  group by  ccy

```
select m.ccy, m.time, m.fxrate 
from my_table  m
inner join  (
  select ccy, max(time) max_time  
  from my_table  
  group by ccy
) t on t.ccy = m.ccy and t.max_time = m.time
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ccy , time ,fxrate 
from mytable
Inner join(SELECT max(time) maxtime, ccy
            FROM  mytable
            group by ccy ) MAXCCY on maxccy.maxtime = mytable.time and MAXCCY.ccy = mytable.ccy
```